# Python Wrapper/Decorator

Tags: python-3.x, decorator, wrapper

I'm trying to figure out wrappers/decorators.

For that, I wanted to create a simple wrapper that creates the directory used in a function if it does not exist:

```
import os

def _create_folder(func):
    def wrapper(directory):
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(directory)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(directory))
        func(directory)
    return wrapper

@_create_folder
def print_dir(directory):
    print(directory)

path = "C:/Temp"
print_dir(path)
```

I have no error, but the folder is not created. What am I missing?

Moreover, at the end, the function that will be wrapped is in a class:

```
import os

def _create_folder(func):
    def wrapper(directory):
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(directory)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(directory))
        func(directory)
    return wrapper

class Test():
    @_create_folder
    def print_dir(self, directory):
        print(directory)

path = "C:/Temp"
test = Test().print_dir(path)
```

In that case, I have the following error:

```
TypeError: wrapper() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

How to make it work inside a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the class, I just needed to handle the "self" in the decorator:

```
def create_folder(func):
    def wrapper(self, directory):
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(directory)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(directory))
        func(self, directory)
    return wrapper

class Test():
    @create_folder
    def print_dir(self, directory):
        print(directory)

path = "C:/Temp/"
test = Test().print_dir(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first code, you should add '/' at the last of path.

```
path="C:/Temp/"
```

**os.path.dirname()** function can recognize using '/' or '\' whether some word is a folder or not.

So, in your code, os.path.dirname() function only returns "C:".